# PIXI Endlessly move sprite over the scene (show at the top as much as hide in bottom)

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

There is endlessly moving sprite "green block" from top to bottom and it works. Is it possible to show sprite moving like "around" the stage show at the top as much as hide in bottom. I don't know exactly how this effect can be called, but I mean when green block is starting to move down the scene border, then start showing it again at the top. How can it be done and can you, please, show how to do this?

[image: Start]

[image: Overflow]

```js
const WIDTH = 500;
const HEIGHT = 500;

const app = new PIXI.Application({ 
    width: WIDTH,
    height: HEIGHT,
    backgroundColor: 0x000000 
});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const sprite = PIXI.Sprite.from('https://i.ibb.co/b3Sjn6M/greeenblock.png');

sprite.width = 100;
sprite.height = 100;

// Center
sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
sprite.x = app.screen.width / 2;
sprite.y = app.screen.height / 2;

app.stage.addChild(sprite);

// Listen for animate update
app.ticker.add((delta) => {

    // Move from topto bottom
    sprite.position.y += delta * 2;
    if (sprite.position.y > HEIGHT + sprite.height / 2) {
        sprite.position.y = -sprite.height / 2;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.3.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Solution (with flickering) provided by @Blindman67:

```js
const WIDTH = 500;
const HEIGHT = 500;

const app = new PIXI.Application({ 
    width: WIDTH,
    height: HEIGHT,
    backgroundColor: 0x000000 
});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const sprite = PIXI.Sprite.from('https://i.ibb.co/b3Sjn6M/greeenblock.png');
const spriteReverse = PIXI.Sprite.from('https://i.ibb.co/b3Sjn6M/greeenblock.png');

sprite.width = 100;
sprite.height = 100;

spriteReverse.width = 100;
spriteReverse.height = 100;

// Center
sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
sprite.x = app.screen.width / 2;
sprite.y = app.screen.height / 2;

spriteReverse.anchor.set(0.5);
spriteReverse.x = app.screen.width / 2;
spriteReverse.y = app.screen.height / 2;

app.stage.addChild(sprite);
app.stage.addChild(spriteReverse);

let y = 0;

// Euqlidian modulo
const modAbs = (value, modulo) => (value % modulo + modulo) % modulo;

// Listen for animate update
app.ticker.add((delta) => {

    // Move from topto bottom
    y += delta * 2;
    if (y > HEIGHT + sprite.height / 2) {
        y = -sprite.height / 2;
    }

    // use modulo to warp
    y = modAbs(y, HEIGHT);

    // check if sprite overlaps the screen edge
    spriteReverse.visible = false;
    if (y + sprite.height > HEIGHT) {   // is crossing then
       spriteReverse.visible = true;
       spriteReverse.position.y =  (y - HEIGHT) // ...   draw a copy at opposite edge.
    }

    sprite.position.y = y
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.3.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `%` Remainder operator

This can be done using the remainder operator [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)

For example if the screen is 1000 pixels wide and you have a coordinate of 1500, that is the object has warped around the screen 1.5 times, using the remainder operator `1500 % 1000 = 500`.

If only moving in a positive direction then this is all that is needed (apart from popping)

```
 x = x % screenWidth; 
 // and/or for y
 y = y % screenHeight;
```

### Negative space

However there is a problem if the object moves in the other direction as the remainder operation keeps the sign of the number `-1500 % 1000 === -500`, and even worse if you use `Math.abs` on the result you still get the wrong value `Math.abs(-1200 % 1000) === 200` which should be 800

You can fix this using a slightly more complex function. You can add it to the `Math` object or use a stand alone function as follows.

```
 const modAbs = (value, modulo) => (value % modulo + modulo) % modulo;
```

With the above function negative values are correctly moved into positive space.

So if you have a coordinate x, y to make it warp the screen with

```
x = modAbs(x, screenWidth);
y = modAbs(y, screenHeight);
```

That seams easy, but unfortunately there are still some problems to overcome.

### Popping

Using the above function to warp across the screen does not consider the size of the sprite, and because you are rendering only one copy when the sprite is move across the playfield edge it will not appear at the other side until the coordinate crossed the edge.

This causes the sprite to pop in and or out depending on the direction of movement and the position of the sprites origin.

There are two solutions.

#### Extend the playfield

If you make the playfield larger than the view (Viewable area) by 2 times the size of the sprite and warp using the larger playfield then the sprite will not warp until it has completely disappeared from view. This prevents the ugly popping in and out when warping and is most suited to NPC type sprites. For player (focused) sprites this is not a good options as the sprite will not be completely visible as it crosses the screen edges.

#### Render extra copies.

To keep the sprite fully visible at all times you need to render it more than once when it is crossing the screen. Example pseudo code

```
 // use modulo to warp
 x = modAbs(x, screenWidth);

 // check if sprite overlaps the screen edge
 if (x + spriteWidth > screenWidth) {   // is crossing then
      drawSprite(x - screenWidth, // ...   draw a copy at opposite edge.
```

If you are only warping between top and bottom (or left and right) this is all that is needed.

If you are warping in all directions you will need to render the sprite up to 4 times. Twice when crossing top bottom or left right. 4 times if crossing in a corner.

As your question only indicates up and down warps I assume you don't need the extra code.

Comment: @gman ?? `((n % m) + m) % m` is identical  to `(value % modulo + modulo) % modulo` There is no need for the inner group `()` as `%` has precedence over `+`. I do not agree with the argument against extending API's (there are many ways to do it safely) however I will remove it from the answer as the finer details are outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Sorry, it was late at night, i mis-read your mod function. On the other hand there is no safe way to extend native objects. You add modAbs, some other lib adds a different modAbs that functions differently, sure you can check that is wasn't modded, how is that safe? It just means when you find out it was you now have to refactor your code. It also assumes some other lib doesn't change it later. But the worst part is it confuses anyone looking at your code. They see `Math.modAbs` and they think it's a built in function.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation, but can I ask you for an working example? I am not sure I understand how to implement this (where is the delta, and etc).

Comment: Ok, I managed somehow to add your solution (updated question with working example), but it's "flickering", when sprite is moving out of black stage. How can prevent/improve this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you: you have one box which you wish to move in an infinite loop from the top to the bottom. Once it hits the bottom it should start showing at the top.

The easiest way I can think of would be to have two identical boxes.
Both starts at the top and only one moves down. Once it hits the bottom the other box can start moving down.
When the first box is completely off-screen you reset it's position.
And repeat.

Comment: Yes, this is what I would like to achieve. Thank you! I never worked with this technologie before, so for me it sounds little weird, to have two objects, but if this is the best way then, can I ask you for the example?